# Sharepoint 2010 Lists - Any limit on the number of views

Tags: 2010, list, view

Is there a limit to the number of views that can be applied to a sharepoint 2010 list?
I have a list on my base site, want a different slice of the list (view) on each subsite where it is not editable.
I will ultimately have 100+ subsites which will each require a different view. 
If you have a better solution please advise.

Answer (score 1):

When you say a view on each subsite, how are you generating the view on each sub site? I'm guessing you're either using the content query web part (CQWP), search or something custom. These aren't necessarily "Views" per SharePoint's term, as a view is a XAML defined view of data on a list. If you're rolling data down to subsites, you can't use this "View" methodology. If you're using a CQWP or search, then you can make as many as you need, since they're not views, but rather queries against the list.

How many items are in the source list? There are limitations here both in storage and how many items you plan to return to each query/view: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a site where the list resides in and different subsites under main site that will be querying over the list with different view.

If you are using the UI only 50 views are allowed (according to MS Support) but I don't know if programmatically you can access with the name of the view.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293299/moss-2007-maximum-number-of-views-for-one-list) there is a discussion about this